# fancybox image and text inside a dynamic scroller

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have a scroller maked with a plugin called simplyscroll.js in jquery. Inside It I scroll many images loaded at runtime using a database. I want to apply at every image a fancybox of the image with some text loaded by database:
(The text that I wanto to load is inside `$img['txt']`)
code:

```
<ul id="scroller2">
<?php
   $qry_img= $db->query("SELECT * FROM image_prodotti;");
   while( $img = $qry_img->fetch_array() ){
    echo '<li class="new"><a href="img/prodotti/caricati/'.$img['url'].'" class="fancy"><img src="img/prodotti/caricati/'.$img['url'].'" alt="" /></a></li>';
 ?>          
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.fancy").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'fade',
        'transitionOut' :   'fade',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where do you want to apply the text? ... on the fancybox title?

Comment: On the fancybox when appear.. in the title is perfect, I have to seen that text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be three possible ways to do it :

**First** (the easiest and simplest) -  Add a `title` attribute to the `<a>` tag and set `$img['txt']` as its value:

```
<ul id="scroller2">
<?php
   $qry_img= $db->query("SELECT * FROM image_prodotti;");
   while( $img = $qry_img->fetch_array() ){
    echo '<li class="new"><a href="img/prodotti/caricati/'.$img['url'].'" title="'.$img['txt'].'" class="fancy"><img src="img/prodotti/caricati/'.$img['url'].'" alt="" /></a></li>';
 ?>          
</ul>
```

You don't need to do any modification to your script. **Notice** that with this option, the `title` will show up as `tooltip` when you hover the thumbnail.

**Second** - Set `$img['txt']` as the value of the `alt` attribute in the thumbnail (`<img>` tag) :

```
<ul id="scroller2">
<?php
   $qry_img= $db->query("SELECT * FROM image_prodotti;");
   while( $img = $qry_img->fetch_array() ){
    echo '<li class="new"><a href="img/prodotti/caricati/'.$img['url'].'" class="fancy"><img src="img/prodotti/caricati/'.$img['url'].'" alt="'.$img['txt'].'" /></a></li>';
 ?>          
</ul>
```

Then add the API option `'titleFromAlt':true` to your script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.fancy").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'fade',
    'transitionOut' :   'fade',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   true,
    'titleFromAlt'  :   true // NEW
  }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**Third** - Depending on the amount of text, you may prefer to store `$img['txt']` in a hidden `<div>` just right after the `<a>` tag; then set its content as the fancybox `title` once it is opened :

```
<ul id="scroller2">
<?php
   $qry_img= $db->query("SELECT * FROM image_prodotti;");
   while( $img = $qry_img->fetch_array() ){
    echo '<li class="new"><a href="img/prodotti/caricati/'.$img['url'].'" class="fancy"><img src="img/prodotti/caricati/'.$img['url'].'" alt="" /></a><div style="display: none;">'.$img['txt'].'</div></li>';
 ?>          
</ul>
```

Then use this script to fetch the contents of the hidden `<div>` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.fancy").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :  'fade',
    'transitionOut' :  'fade',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   true,
    'titlePosition' :  'over', // NEW
    'onStart'       :   function(currentArray,currentIndex){
       var obj = currentArray[ currentIndex ];
       this.title = $(obj).next('div').html();
    }
  }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

**NOTE** : this is for `fancybox v1.3.2 +`